# Python Selenium Find Partial Link Text from a List

Tags: python, selenium

I have text already scrapped into a list A=[' Workers east', ' Worker united'].
What I'm trying to do is from A, find in the browser the words Worker united and click on it, I'm trying this:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("%s" %(A[1])).click()
```

But is not working, it doesn´t find the element. Below is the HTML Code and working with:

```
<ul style="display: block;">
    <li class="">
        <a class="text  active" href="/es/news/UK/London/workers-united---team">
            Workers United - Team
            <div style="top: -1.5px;" class="marker"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I will appreciate any help you could give me, thanks!

Comment: The error I've got is this: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":" Workers United"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you have has `Workers United - Team` inside the text, but you are searching for `Worker united` - watch the `s` and the case.

Also, remove the leading spaces in the strings inside the `A` list.

Answer (score 3):

The text you are looking for is:

> Worker united

The text that exists on the page is:

> Workers United

Selenium is case sensitive.  Capitalize the `u` in your python script

Additionally, as pointed out by @alecxe, your pluralization for `worker` is incorrect.  The page displays "worker**s**" *(plural)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPATH: //a[contains(text(), 'Worker')]